# Story of Khalid ibn Walid cooking Malik bin Nuwayrah head?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Please forgive me for asking this question, but for the purposes of edification we are commanded to seek the truth. Is this narration authentic?

وأمر برأسه فجعل مع حجرين وطبخ على الثلاثة قدرا فأكل منها خالد تلك الليلة ليرهب بذلك الأعراب من المرتدة وغيرهم

He (Khalid) ordered that the head (of Malik) be placed with two stones and inserted into a cooking pot, he (Khalid) then ate from it that night in order scare the Arabs and others from being apostates.

al-Bidayah wa al-Nihaya, Volume 6 page 354

Comment: you will find the answer here : http://alkulify.blogspot.com/2014/04/blog-post_9.html?m=1

Comment: If the question is about authentication maybe the tags should be changed!

Comment: The story as is in al-Bidayah wa an-Nihaya is not referred to any source!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this narration authentic?

No, it is not authentic.

**1. Here is part of the text in the original arabic [source](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=714&idto=714&bk_no=59&ID=780)**

> واصطفى خالد امرأة مالك بن نويرة ، وهي أم تميم ابنة المنهال ، وكانت
>   جميلة ، فلما حلت بنى بها . ***ويقال*** : بل استدعى خالد مالك بن
>   نويرة فأنبه على ما صدر منه من متابعة سجاح ، وعلى منعه الزكاة ، وقال :
>   ألم تعلم أنها قرينة الصلاة ؟ فقال مالك : إن صاحبكم كان يزعم ذلك . فقال
>   : أهو صاحبنا وليس بصاحبك ؟ ! يا ضرار ، اضرب عنقه . فضرب عنقه ، وأمر
>   برأسه فجعل مع حجرين ، وطبخ على الثلاثة قدرا ، فأكل منها خالد تلك
>   الليلة ليرهب بذلك الأعراب من المرتدة وغيرهم . ***ويقال*** : إن
>   شعر مالك جعلت النار تعمل فيه إلى أن نضج لحم القدر ، ولم يفرغ الشعر
>   لكثرته . وقد تكلم أبو قتادة مع خالد فيما صنع ، وتقاولا في ذلك ، حتى
>   ذهب أبو قتادة فشكاه إلى الصديق ، وتكلم عمر مع أبي قتادة في خالد ،
>   وقال للصديق : اعزله ، فإن في سيفه رهقا

As you see the author said "ويقال" , and it means "and it is said". as you see the author did not bring the chain of transmision. without source and chain of transmision we cannot consider a story as authentic.

**2. Here you find [Imam Nawawī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi) explaining that when we say "it is said" ,then the Hadith is weak...**

> صيغة التمريض (رُوِيَ ) و ( يُروى ) و ( ذُكِر ) ونحوها : هي صيغة تعني
>   عند علماء الحديث المتأخرين : تضعيف الرّاوي أو تضعيف الحديث أو هي أداء
>   الحديث بصيغة تحتمل عدم الثبوت أو تطرق الشك إليه في الغالب ، قال الإمام
>   النووي رحمه الله ورضي عنه في " المجموع " ( 1 / 63 ) : " قال العلماء
>   المحققون من أهل الحديث وغيرهم : إذا كان الحديث ضعيفاً لا يقال فيه قال
>   رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أو فعل أو أمر أو نهى أو حكم ، وما أشبه
>   ذلك من صيغ الجزم ، وكذا لا يقال فيه رَوى أبو هريرة أو قال أو ذكر أو
>   أخبر أو حدث أو نقل أو أفتى وما أشبهه ، وكذا لا يقال ذلك في التابعين
>   ومن بعدهم فيما كان ضعيفاً فلا يقال في شيء من ذلك بصيغة الجزم .
>
> وإنما يقال في هذا كله رُوِيَ عنه أو نُقل عنه أو حُكي عنه أو جاء عنه أو
>   بلغنا عنه أو يقال أو يذكر أو يحكى أو يروى أو يرفع أو يعزى ، وما أشبه
>   ذلك من صيغ التمريض وليست من صيغ الجزم . قالوا فصيغ الجزم موضوعة للصحيح
>   أو الحسن ، وصيغ التمريض لما سواهما .

**3. And now let's look in the content of the story, the author said:**

> **ويقال : إن شعر مالك جعلت النار تعمل فيه إلى أن نضج لحم القدر ، ولم يفرغ الشعر لكثرته**

**It is said that the hair of Malik made the fire work until the flesh of the pot had matured, and the hair was not emptied for its multitude.**  (translated using Google Translator, I could not find the translation of all the book in english)

As you know the fire when it is approached to the hair, the fire eat it immediately after touching it, but this story says "the hair of Malik made the fire work until the flesh of the pot had matured"!
how can this be possible? cooking the flesh using the hair of someone is impossible, the hair will be consumed by the fire soon before making the water hot... so this story is a lie...

*Sorry for my english...*